# Android Studio says: duplicate class found

Tags: android-studio, class

Android Studio throws "duplicate class found" at me, but I did not do anything:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.DirectoryEntriesReader found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilder found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilderImpl found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorImpl found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.LinkFollowing found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathNode found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$bfsIterator$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$dfsIterator$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalkKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathWalkOption found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.21)
```

and so on ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate class in Kotlin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75263047/duplicate-class-in-kotlin-android)

Answer (score 105):

just add

```
implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
```

in dependencies

it solved my problem.

Comment: thanks its works android giraffe preview 2023

Comment: Life saver. Works on Electric eel

Comment: worked only for debug release. For signed release i am getting this error "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0."

Comment: @Tara your may be other libraries version are not updated, 1.8.0 is latest version than 1.6.0 right? so you may need to update all other libraries to latest version than this solution will work.

Comment: @Dhvani023 all libs are upto date. The only issue was gradle. I have to update the gradle to the latest and ta-da error gone :-D

Answer (score 12):

This is possible same as this question: [Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75319750/16765223)

I faced this problem due to these 2 plugins

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
```

Just downgrading from 2.6.1 to 2.5.1

Like below

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
```

If the above solution does not affect anything, try downgrading some plugins you just upgraded. It'll definitely resolve.

I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 10):

**It worked for me, I'm sure it will work for you too**

open you project `gradle.properties`

add this code `android.enableJetifier=true` below `android.useAndroidX=true`

then open `build.gradle`

And add this dependency

```
dependencies {
         // your project dependency
    constraints{
          implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0'
          implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0'  
        }
}
```

sync and it will work

Comment: This solution gives me warnings "'implementation' is defined by 'dependencies' but used within 'constraints'". How can I solve that please ?

Answer (score 7):

The following advice in [JetBrains issue KT 54136](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54136/Duplicated-classes-cause-build-failure-if-a-dependency-to-kotlin-stdlib-specified-in-an-android-project) has helped me - append the following to the `dependencies` section in your app `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    // ....

    constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Did you try this way ? :

```
implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
```

Comment: This working!! thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You must upgrade the Android Gradle Plugin to 1.8.0 on the top level build file.

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert, but this same issue happened to me after changing my Kotlin version from 1.7.0 to 1.8.0. Check your app-level `build.gradle` file to make sure you're using your desired version (in your case, I believe it should be 1.8.0):

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my project I have to update project `build.gradle`

from

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10'
```

to

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `build.gradle`:

```
implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
```

Sync then **remove** the above implementation `build.gradle` and Sync **again**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the same problem but with of duplicated classes, but betwen the version 1.9.0 and 1.7.10:
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
. . .

My project is a Flutter project.

I got the solution modifying the file gradle.properties from the Android directory:

From:

plugins {

```
id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
id "com.android.application" version '8.3.0' apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
```

}

To:

plugins {

```
id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
id "com.android.application" version '8.3.0' apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.0" apply false
```

}