# Why am I seeing duplicate class errors in kotlin stdlib modules on android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling

Duplicate class `kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4` found in modules `kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10)` and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)`

Duplicate class `kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt` found in modules `kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10)` and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)`

Duplicate class `kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt` found in modules `kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10)` and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)`

Tried to look for solutions on youtube :( didn't work

Comment: Try this solution -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/75974885/16765223 Let me know solved or not